# What is lifetime of custom view extends ViewPart in Eclipse platform?

Tags: eclipse, view, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

What is lifetime of a custom view which extends `ViewPart` in Eclipse platform?

Is it created when View appears and destroyed when it disappears?

If so then why creation occurs in method `createPartControl()` but not in constructor?

Comment: It's a fairly good question, but I can't imagine why would you want to know that. I hope you're not instantiating views yourself. :-)

Comment: But I store data inside it.

Comment: If it's big data, then you shouldn't...

Comment: I want to judge myslef

Answer (score 2):

The view part is constructed the first time it needs to be shown. `createPartControl` is called during this construction but the

```
public void init(IViewSite site);
```

and

```
public void init(IViewSite site, IMemento memento);
```

methods are called before `createPartControl` to allow some things to be initialized. The base `ViewPart` class normally deals with this but the methods can be overridden if required.

Updated:
Although the API to 'close' a view is actually called `hideView` it does appear to call the `dispose` method of the view and reconstructs it on the next use. If the view is open on multiple perspectives it is not disposed until the last reference is closed.

Comment: Also is it destroyed when the given Viewpart is closed from **ALL THE PERSPECTIVES??**

Comment: @ChandrayyaGK The view is disposed when the last reference to it is closed